# Any idioms about "You never wake a people who pretend to be sleeping"

Tags: idioms

I would like to know, when you ask someone for something, but he ignore it all the time, and pretend he didn't know your request. Any idioms I can use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A very useful forum. Thank you so much, @Emma!

Comment: How can you wake someone that is pretending to be sleeping? If he's pretending then he's not really sleeping. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pretend

Comment: You probably meant to say **You can never wake a person who pretends to be asleep**. Meaning, you can never get the person to hear your requests because he is not merely ignoring you out of distraction towards some other business, but does that on purpose, only pretending to be distracted by something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [To turn a blind eye](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+blind+eye)

seems like a phrase you could use. It is very commonly used in general English.

For example:

> George was turning a blind eye to Jane's frequent requests for help.

It means either 'ignore' or 'procastinate' depending on context.

> Fred was turning a blind eye to the pile of work on his desk.
>
> To turn a deaf ear.

means pretty much exactly the same thing.

I don't think there is a direct equivalent of 'you can't wake a person pretending to be sleeping', but:

> There's none so blind as those who will not see.

Means:

> You can't force someone to recognise/accept a fact they don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

In figurative terms, the most common idiom is [**let sleeping dogs lie**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20sleeping%20dogs%20lie):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : to ignore a problem because trying to deal with it could cause an even more difficult situation
>   // I thought about bringing up my concerns but decided instead to let sleeping dogs lie.

It's rarely used in the case of a *literal* dog (or anyone) that's sleeping. It just means to stop bringing up old issues.

In your case, if the person keeps pretending to not hear your request, it's likely because they don't want to deal with it—and it's best to ***stop*** pestering them. (If you don't, it could make the matter worse than just not getting what you want from them.)

Comment: The user probably wants to know English counterparts to a saying "You **can never** wake a person who pretends to be asleep".